# Remove blank spaces to the left and right of texts or numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove blank spaces to the left and right of texts or numbers.

I would like to use a VBA code.

As I now apply formulas in each cell of my spreadsheet this will save me a lot of work.

The formulas that works cell by cell:

For numbers:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(160);CHAR(32)))*1
```

For texts and empty cells:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(160);CHAR(32)))
```

I found this VBA code on the internet. It doesn't solve my case. What I found interesting is that it generates a box asking to select cells.

```
Sub Clear()
Dim rLocal As Range

'Assignment of variables
Set rLocal = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the cells you want to clear...", Type:=8)

rLocal.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=""
End Sub
```

I found the following code that worked when I changed "" to " ". It seems to be quite heavy and seems to make the same substitution several times.

```
Public Sub RemoveSpaceInString()    
    Dim myCell As Range            
    For Each myCell In Selection
        myCell = Trim(myCell)
        myCell = Replace(myCell, vbTab, "")
        myCell = Replace(myCell, " ", "")
        myCell = Replace(myCell, Chr(160), "")
    Next myCell    
End Sub
```

If it is not possible to create the Application.InputBox, the code will make this change for all spreadsheets in the Excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Public Sub RemoveSpaceInString()
Dim myCell As Range

For I = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Activate

Set selrange = Selection

For Each myCell In selrange
    myCell = Trim(myCell)
    myCell = Replace(myCell, vbTab, "")
    myCell = Replace(myCell, Chr(160), "")
Next myCell
Next I

End Sub
```

Now, you can run code on selection in any worksheet.

If you want to run code on any predefined range, then you need to replace the selection with that predefined range.

Comment: Dear Brian,

The code analyzed the entire workbook, but only made changes to the spreadsheet I was viewing.

Additionally, it removed all spaces, including the space between words. Example: "My name is"> "Mynameis"

I would just like him to remove the spaces to the left and right of the texts and numbers. Example: "Testing"> "Testing". "I am 50"> "I am 50".

It is possible to have two types of code: one to generate a box asking me to select the cells in which the code will be applied and other the same as you did: for all worksheets in the workbook?

Thanks.

João.

Comment: Select the range on each sheet in the workbook that you want to change. And then run above code, It will run on each sheet and make changes to each already selected range. Moreover, I have removed the replace code so now it will not remove the spaces between words now.